# Show the custom tool menu under Resources menu using laravel nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I just followed all the steps to make a custom Tool Laravel/Nova/custom/tools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtCq9.png)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel nova v3 you cant change the layout custom-made tools.

If you really want to do this you'll have to come up with a little bit of javascript to flip the HTML elements.

Custom tools are always last in the menu.

I advise you to upgrade to laravel nova 4, this gives way more menu customization possibilities and its the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/dcasia/collapsible-resource-manager.
It will allow to place custom tool menu under resource using RawResource::make().